# Elastic beanstalk + Spring Boot + Array properties

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, properties-file

I need to pass some configuration to my Spring Boot app, which is deployed using elastic beanstalk.

Unfortunately, I need to update these variables without recompilation of the artifact, so I want to use the uppercase with underscore notation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-configuration.html). Unfortuanatelly the configuration is more complex, in fact I am trying to pass array of objects into it (which is supported in the properties files/yaml - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml). But the properties syntax requires brackets (**[ ]**).

Is there any way, how to workaround this (without rewriting the application)?

Comment: Did you look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

Comment: The problem is that I need to update the properties without repackaging the software (in fact support will do this). If I understand the extensions correctly, its not possible to deploy them separately from the app...

Answer (score 0):

According to me, following should work:

- Add all your external properties as documented on [aws documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-configuration.html)
- Use these properties in your spring boot application with @value annotation. If you see the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) the property source at order 9/10  should get the values of your properties.

Comment: Yes, I know this... but I need to pass array of objects in the property, which does not seem to be possible this way..